# Power BI Real-Time Streaming with SQL Data using Azure Stream Analytics Job

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi, real-time-data, azure-analytics

I am new to Azure Analytics. My Issue is to unable to connect to Power BI with Stream Analytics Job.
FYI, I can't edit configuration files of my IoT devices. I only have my Sensors data in SQL Server. I want that data to be live stream to Power BI using Azure Analytics Job. I have already created SQL Database in Azure. I am struck at passing the Input, Output and Query details with reference to the SQL Data. Please help me to get out of it.
Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 0):

In Stream Analytics Job, give reference of your SQL

Go to **Inputs >> Add reference input >> SQL Database**

[image: Ref1]

And fill in all the details of database, create delta query, and click on `save`.

**For output:**

**Go to Output >> Add >> Power BI**

[image: Ref2]

And fill in all the details of Power BI like Dataset name, table name output alias and obtain **authorization** to connect to Power BI using your own `user identity`.

**Please refer the below links for more information :-**

[Use reference data from a SQL Database for an Azure Stream Analytics job provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-reference-data)

[Stream Analytics and Power BI: A real-time analytics dashboard for streaming data provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard)

Comment: Hi, I've gone through the links you mentioned. Here is the case,
First of all, I don't want to run IoT Simulator which mentioned in application or any other IoT Device, instead I want to know whether it is possible to stream the input with SQL Table data only which is stored in Azure Database. Please help me